# O que é aceitável ou recomendado ao editar uma resposta para incluir conteúdo de outra?

Tags: debate, comportamento

[Nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3030/como-desfaco-o-ultimo-commit-no-git/3038) sugeri que o usuário editasse a resposta mais votada para incluir conteúdo já respondido por outros usuários. Assim a primeira resposta ficaria mais completa e seria mais útil para quem viesse a consultar no futuro.

Qual a atitude recomendada para este tipo de situação?

Answer (score 8):

**Não precisa ter todo o conhecimento necessário em uma resposta**. É saudável ter várias respostas, cada uma ajudando a outra.

Eventualmente até pode ser feito isso, mas o ideal é que cada uma dê sua própria resposta. Se a pessoa acha que realmente alguma coisa vai ajudar sua própria resposta, ok. Mas seria bom, avisar que foi baseado na resposta do outro.

A **minha** recomendação é usar esse recurso com moderação, apenas quando realmente é importante, dando o devido crédito.